# Way to match *all* newline-type character sequences in a text file

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I'm looking for a way to obtain all sequences of newline-like characters found in a string.  I'm trying to use preg_match() as follows:

```
preg_match('/^[^\r\n]*(?:([\r\n]+)|[^\r\n]*)+$/', $input_text, $matches);
```

But I only appear to be getting the *last* such match.  I feel like the solution probably involves the use of \G, but when I attempt to introduce it, the match fails entirely.  I don't think I'm understanding how to use it correctly or where it should go.

I realize my pattern will match multiple newlines in sequence (i.e. blank lines lead to multiple newlines in a single match).  This is what I want.

For example, for the string:

```
"ABC\nDEF\r\n\rGHI\n\n\r\n",
```

I would like to get:

```
[ "\n", "\r\n\r", "\n\n\r\n" ]
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```php
preg_match_all('/\R+/u', "ABC\nDEF\r\n\rGHI\n\n\r\n", $matches);
```

It returns all line ending sequences because `\R+` matches one or more line ending sequences.